# Unhide and hide contents within the div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello after searching most of the answers on stackoverflow about hiding and unhiding stuffs within the div I don't get the proper answer because most of them depends on the form.My scenario is that I have the textarea that I want it to be tapped and as soon as the person start typing the div expands and show some extra buttons like Post or Cancel button, good example is google+ "Share what's new" home screen.

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function(){
            $('textarea').click(function(){
                $('button').show().removeAttr('disabled');
                $('.second').show();                  
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <div>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <br>
        <div class="second" style="display: none" disabled>
        <label>Where:</label><button>place1</button> Or <button>Place2</button><br>
        <label>Tags:</label><button>Good Service</button>
        <button>Minor</button>
        <button>Major</button>

        </div>
        <button id="cancel" style="display: none" disabled>Cancel</button>
        <button id="cancel" style="display: none" disabled>POST</button>
   </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: In this community we are happy to help one another create better code and solve problems. Though, with this question, it seems like you us to write it for you, which is simply what Stackoverflow was not created for. If you would provide some code examples of what you have tried, we would be more than happy to assist you.

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for something like this?

All you have to do is, handle the keypress events and check for the length of the values in the textbox to show or hide controls.

```html
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript"> 
                    $(function(){
                        $('textarea').on('keypress keydown keyup', function(){
                          if ($(this).val().length >0)
                            {
                               $('button').show().removeAttr('disabled');
                               $('.second').show();        
                            }
                          else                
                            {
                              $('button').hide().prop('disabled', true);
                               $('.second').hide();   
                            }
                        });
                      
                      $('#cancel').on('click', function(){                     
                        $('textarea').val('').trigger('keypress');
                        });
                    });
                </script>

            </head>
            <body>
                <form>
                <div>
                    <textarea></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <div class="second" style="display: none" disabled>
                    <label>Where:</label><button>place1</button> Or <button>Place2</button><br>
                    <label>Tags:</label><button>Good Service</button>
                    <button>Minor</button>
                    <button>Major</button>

                    </div>
                    <button id="cancel" style="display: none" disabled>Cancel</button>
                    <button id="post" style="display: none" disabled>POST</button>
               </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Good example but is like now the cancel button is disabled.I am trying to fix it to cancel the expansion.

Comment: @CleopasManams, I have added 'cancel' event handler as well. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
<button type="button" class="btnPost" style="display:none" id="btnPost" text="Post"/>
<button type="button" class="btnCancel" style="display:none" id="btnCancel" text="Cancel"/>
```

And your **`TextArea`**'s class is `txtArea1` , Then your script can be :

```
$(".txtArea1").click(fucntion(){
      $(".btnPost").show();
      $(".btnCancel).show();
});
```

**OR**

You can change the css from the script as :

```
 $(".txtArea1").click(fucntion(){
          $(".btnPost").css("display","block");
          $(".btnCancel).show("display,"block");
    });
```

*And* to increase dynamically the size of your text area you can visit this [site](http://plugins.jquery.com/autogrow/)

Answer (score 0):

I created an example in jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/qbemat6n/

```
<div id='additionalbuttons' style='display:none;'>
    Additional Buttons: <button >Submit</button><button >Clear</button>
</div>
<textarea id="status" placeholder="Write here..." name="new_entry"></textarea>

$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#status').focus(function() {
        $('#additionalbuttons').fadeIn(200);
    });
});
```

And, here how it applies to your existing code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#status').focus(function() {
        $('#second').fadeIn(200);               
    });
});

 <div>
     <textarea id="status" ></textarea>
     <br>

     <div class="second" style="display: none" disabled>
         <label>Where:</label><button>place1</button> Or <button>Place2</button>  <br>
        <label>Tags:</label><button>Good Service</button>

         <button>Minor</button>
         <button>Major</button>
    </div>

    <button id="cancel" style="display: none" disabled>Cancel</button>
    <button id="cancel" style="display: none" disabled>POST</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: i don't want to use form tag at all.Is there way that I can remove form tag and work with divs only ?

Comment: why not (as long as you are not trying to post any form data).. you can just exclude them. I updated the code.